# Is the programmatic addition of keywords and descriptions worthwhile?

Tags: seo, keywords, asp.net, meta-tags, meta-description

I see here: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1648/seo-for-aspnet-web-site/

this code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Add meta description tag
  HtmlMeta metaDescription = new HtmlMeta();
  metaDescription.Name = "Description";
  metaDescription.Content = "All winners of major book, movie, and music awards, namely Pulitzers, National Book Awards, National Outdoors Book Awards, National Book Critics Circle, Hugos, Oscars/Academy Awards, Sundance, Cannes, Golden Globes, Grammies, American Music Awards, Country Music Awards, Indies";
  Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaDescription);

  // Add meta keywords tag
  HtmlMeta metaKeywords = new HtmlMeta();
  metaKeywords.Name = "Keywords";
  metaKeywords.Content = "Books, Movies, Music, Prizes, Awards, Pulitzer, Pulitzers, National Book Critics Circle, National Book Awards, National Outdoors Book Awards, Hugos, Academy Awards, Oscars, Golden Globe, Cannes, Cannes Film Festival, Sundance, Sundance Film Festival, Grammy, Grammies, American Music Awards, AMA, Country Music Awards, CMA, Indies, Indies Music Awards, Amazon";
  Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaKeywords);
}
```

...but if you already have the description and keywords in your html, like so:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Books, Movies, Music, Prizes, Awards, Pulitzer, Pulitzers, National Book Critics Circle, National Book Awards, National Outdoors Book Awards, Hugos, Academy Awards, Oscars, Golden Globe, Cannes, Cannes Film Festival, Sundance, Sundance Film Festival, Grammy, Grammies, American Music Awards, AMA, Country Music Awards, CMA, Indies, Indies Music Awards, Amazon" />
<meta name="description" content="All winners of major book, movie, and music awards, namely Pulitzers, National Book Awards, National Outdoors Book Awards, National Book Critics Circle, Hugos, Oscars/Academy Awards, Sundance, Cannes, Golden Globes, Grammies, American Music Awards, Country Music Awards, Indies" />
```

...would adding the code be a waste of time? What effect would it have?

Comment: Looks like it would just cause duplicate meta tags

Comment: That's what I was thinking; so I wonder why this would be suggested in the first place (as it seems easier to just add it to the html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta keywords are [not used by Google at all](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html).  Bing may use them but they carry almost no weight.  At this point, I recommend that websites omit meta keyword entirely.  They are not worth the effort.

Meta descriptions should be unique to each page.   If you are using a template with some replacement text, then it can be beneficial to generate the meta description programatically:

- Read reviews for $product with prices starting from $price from Bob's general web store
- Read reviews for the bright sun 300 watt light bulb with prices starting from $15.79 from Bob's general web store.

However, your meta description looks like it will come out identical across all pages.  That is not a good idea.  Google will ignore your meta description if it isn't actually descriptive of the specific landing page.

Comment: I only have one page, but it is very dynamic. Can I change the descriptions as I change the content of the div on the one page? Would that make sense/be of any value?

Comment: If you have only one page, then you may set the meta description in that manner.  Your meta description is poorly written though.  It is too long, and doesn't have a call to action.  Tell people why they would want to visit your site.  Tell them what you want them to do on your site.

Comment: Thanks, I'll re-write it; but how do I change the description on the fly. The example above is in C#, but won't I need to do it in jQuery? I'm not aware of any way to hook into the user changing selections in jQuery UI with Razor/C#.

Comment: It looks like I found how to change meta tags dynamically here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page

Comment: If interested, see my follow-up related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934072/why-is-my-dynamic-changing-of-my-meta-description-tag-not-changing-it

Comment: Changing the meta description dynamically won't help with SEO.  Google will only pay attention to what a crawler sees.   One page websites are very hard to get to work from an SEO perspective.